# Display information of object as pop-up when clicking on the name of the object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, popup

Ok, so, I have this lovely view here:

```
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("ConfirmSendItems", "Inventory"))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Item Name</th>
                <th>Other Actions</th>
            </tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListItems.Count; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Ajax.ActionLink(@Model.ListItems[i].m_OtrObj.m_ObjName.ToString(), "GetObjProperties", new {id = @Model.ListItems[i].m_ItemID}, new AjaxOptions{ HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "result", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "openPopup"})</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
</p>
```

And these lovely scripts here :

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopup() {
        alert("We have a new Pope-Up!");
        $("#result").dialog("open");
    }

</script>
```

Which shows the wanted message once I click on the link

I want to open a popUp window that will display the "/GetObjProperties/ method right here:

```
    public PartialViewResult GetObjProperties(int? id)
    {
        ObjInfo objToDisplay = m_ObjManager.GetObjByID(id);

        return PartialView(objToDisplay );
    }
```

*** EDIT ***

Here's a resume of my question:

I want to make a link on the item's name that will open a pop-up window using a partial view.

*** EDIT 2 ***

As of right now, when I click, nothing is done. But if I right-click on the link and click on "Open in a new window", I get the exact good behavior. The problem remains that a pop-up does not open.

Comment: Herve, I've read your question twice and still not sure what you mean. Consider rephrasing

Comment: @DaveA : On my way to editing, plus adding information since I've worked on the problem ever since I've posted the question. You will see what I mean when it is done, I will notify.

Comment: @DaveA I have edited my answer to show the evolution of my work, tell me if any infos are missing or if you have questions.

Comment: I'm begining to see. Can I assume **result** is id of div that has your popup?

Comment: Something like this, there are mistakes in my javascript AND my razor view, bear with me. :S

Comment: @DaveA Now the Ajax Link seems to work, but a new page open instead of a pop-up window.

Comment: window.open('/Inventory/GetCardProperties/' opens a window? You want to do something else there i suppose?

Comment: @CarlPalsson Yes. As of right now I'm trying to build something that would open a pop-up window displaying the information I want. The Ajax link works, but it shows the information in the current page instead of opening a pop-up.

Comment: @CarlPalsson is right. the window.open seems out of place. you already achieve your dialog open. the window.open IS your problems.

Comment: The openPopup() method is never actually called. Everything stays at the Ajax Link.

Comment: because you are NOT returning success

Comment: I have updated my code right now. The openPopup() method is not called, and I don't understand what you mean @DaveA when you say that I am not returning success :S

Comment: Success is not an automatic behavior. It is a JSON object returned by controller. example: http://forums.asp.net/t/1647206.aspx/1

Comment: @DaveA now my method is called. It was because the return value of my controller method returned an ActionResult, not a partialview. Corrected that and I got my method showing the alert I've placed, but no pop-up yet.

Comment: @HerveS, aaaah, i see. good job

Comment: We're close to the truth!

Answer (score 1):

If you need a popup youll need to do it like this -->

```
  <a href="#" onclick="Popup=window.open('testpage1.htm','Popup','toolbar=no,
  location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=no,
  width=420,height=400,left=430,top=23'); return false;">
  Test Window</a>
```

A basic html example ;)

I hope this is answering your question I find it a little hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Check this

```
$(".objDialog").click(function() {
        alert("Card Name has been clicked!");
        window.open('/Inventory/GetCardProperties/', 'ObjProperties',
       'heigth=' + (window.screen.height - 100) + ', width=200, left=' +
       (window.screen.width - 250) + ',top=10,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,
        scrollbars=yes,location=no,menubar=no');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, and you are right, I am not very clear in my question. I will take the time to correct this as soon as I have time enough. :)

Comment: Can I do that with my Ajax Link? I would rather use that instead of an HTML call.

Comment: that was jsut to show you a working example Im sure you can use it to put in your link

Comment: yeah, ok, I think I get what you are telling me. The problem is that this line is never called, so you could ignore it right now. I have tried without and this does not change a thing.

Comment: because the .objDialog is not used. Maybe that's why? I will try adding the class to the Ajax Link, though I thought that an ajax link would do the work...

Comment: I have modified my post so that you may see my code as it is now. If you see anything feel free to point out